# Laravel 9 Storage images error 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, storage

Good day.
I've been dealing with a problem for a couple of days that hadn't happened to me in any other Laravel project.
I use Angular and Ionic(angular) to connect to a VPS where my Laravel 9 project is hosted. I've already run the `php artisan storage:link` command and given permission 775 to the storage folder.

In this same VPS I have more Laravel projects where I upload images with Storage in the same way as in this project

`request()->file('file')->store('public/'.$id);`

This successfully saves the image and I can see it in my storage folder.

Now when I want to see from a browser or from the app that route where the image is, it gives me the error `403 Forbbiden You do not have permission to access this document.`
The route I use is with this structure:

`https://exampledomain.com/storage/1/exampleimg.png`

But if I give it permission 775 again, it already shows the image without any problem, but the new images that are uploaded will not be shown and will continue saying `403 Forbbiden You do not have permission to access this document.`

I cannot be giving permission 775 every time a new image is uploaded since it is a project that will be handled by dozens of people.

The strangest thing is that only in **laravel 9** I have this problem because in my past projects laravel 7, 6, 5.8 all projects upload images and I only had to give permission to the storage folder once.

Comment: Have you tried to set a specific directory with the 775 permission and upload the files there? Don't use the root approach (/)

Comment: Yes, I put the recursive permission to the entire Storage folder
`chmod -R 775 storage/` and all internal folders and files have the necessary permission. But when I upload a new image, this new image does not have permission 775

Comment: and did you try 777?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried with permission 777 and it doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in `.env` file

`FILESYSTEM_DISK=local`

to

`FILESYSTEM_DISK=public`